# How to bulk change the source language of field labels?

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a French Drupal site that needs to be translated into English and Dutch.
My question is only about the translation of the content types fields (label/description/...) which are configuration objects.

When I look at the source language of those fields, it is mostly set to English which is wrong. Approx 20% are set to French, which is fine.

I don't know how it comes but I am there... I would like to change the source language of all those items into French. Is there a way to handle this quickly (I have so many content types each with +/- 30 fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the process I used.

1-export all configuration files: `drush config-export` (see settings.php to get the export directory `$config['sync']=..`

2-copy all the `field.storage.node.field_*.yml` and `field.field.node.*.field_*.yml` into a directory named for example `content-fields`

3-replace the wrong english langcode from within the `content-fields` directory using sed: `` for i in `find *` ; do sed -i -- 's/langcode: en/langcode: fr/g' $i; done ``

4-import back the corrected files by using drush cim with the `partial` attribute: `drush cim --partial --source=<your path>/content-fields`

MAKE SURE TO USE THE PARTIAL ATTRIBUTE TO NOT DELETE MANY CONFIGURATION